# createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord works but listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord does not

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to control a Hands-Free link with my device. The following works just fine:

```
UUID HFP_UUID_GET_HF = UUID.fromString("0000111E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
BluetoothSocket aBluetoothSocket = mDevice
                .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(HFP_UUID_GET_HF);
```

and I get a socket that I can read and right to. No problem. However, I also want to listen for an incoming connection and get that socket. I tried this:

```
UUID HFP_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000111F-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
UUID HFP_UUID_GET_HF = UUID.fromString("0000111E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
BluetoothServerSocket tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("HFP",   HFP_UUID);
BluetoothSocket aBluetoothSocket = tmp.accept();
```

However, even though the two devices connect I never get a socket back. BTW if I use the UUID that starts with 111E in this second code block here I get a service discovery io error, which makes sense -- I know that my device is using uuid 111F and the other device uses UUID 111E.

Has anyone ran into this issue before? I need to be able to have complete control over all data that gets sent from the phone on that rfcomm channel. I cannot use reflection ; i.e.

```
Class<?>[] args = new Class[] { int.class };            
int HFP_CHANNEL = 10;
Method listenOn = BluetoothAdapter.class.getDeclaredMethod("listenUsingRfcommOn", args);
BluetoothServerSocket my_server = (BluetoothServerSocket) (listenOn.invoke(mBluetoothAdapter, 
                new Object[] { HFP_CHANNEL }));
BluetoothSocket m_BluetoothSocket = my_server.accept();
```

because that also throws an io error -- channel already in use, unless anyone knows a way to turn off the hands-free system service. Afaik that is part of bluetoothd (I`m using Android 4.1 here) and I need that to remain running (I`m not sure if I even can turn it off)

Comment: Hi All I am also running into the same problem where i have six devices from which two are master devices and others are slave, i am listening over the master using reflection method by providing port number 4, and for non master devices from the device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord. Master devices never get connects if slave thread is running. @twinPrimesAreEz Please let me know if you got the solution for this.

Comment: @jitain -- For my purposes I wasn`t tied to the android OS, so I just moved to a linux box and modified the bluez source. Could you elaborate a bit more on your problem? What UUIDs are you using, and are you sure your master devices aren`t already connected on that port to one of the slaves, or to a different device?

Comment: The UUID for Master device is: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, Where as for connecting to the slave devices i get the UUID from the device.getUuids() list, and if null UUID mention above will be used. My main problem is, i have many threads for the slave devices to connect with them and running great, and have one server thread listening for the incoming connections, While all Master devices connect great using this server thread if and if only no slave device connecting threads are running.